# Refresh data on click outside controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to grasp the idea behind angular and ran into my first obstacle involving accessing data from outside the scope (the app?)

Here is a very simple example of what I'm trying to do:

HTML:

```
<div class=logo>
    <a href='/refresh'>Refresh</a>
</div>
<div ng-app ng-controller="threadslist">
<div class='thread_list_header'>
    <table class='thread_list_table'>
    <tr class='table_header'>
        <!--1--><td class='table_c1'></td>
        <!--2--><td class='table_c2'>{{name}}</td>
        <!--3--><td class='table_c3'>Cliq</td>
        <!--4--><td class='table_c4'>Last Poster</td>
        <!--5--><td class='table_c5'><a class="clickme">Refresh</a></td>
    </tr></table>
</div>
<table class='thread_list_table' >
    <tr class="thread_list_row" ng-repeat="user in users">
                <!--1--><td class='table_options table_c1'></td>
        <!--2--><td class='table_subject table_c2' title="">{{user.subject}}</td>
                <!--3--><td class='table_cliq table_c3'></td>
                <!--4--><td class='table_last table_c4'><span class="thread_username"><a href=#>{{user.username}}</a></span></td>
                <!--5--><td class='table_reply table_c5'><abbr class="thread_timestamp timeago" title=""></abbr></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function threadslist($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Ricky';

  // Initialising the variable.
  $scope.users = [];
     $http({
    url: '/cliqforum/ajax/ang_thread',
    method: "POST",
  }).success(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data;
  });
  // Getting the list of users through ajax call.
  $('.table_header').on('click', '.clickme', function(){
        $http.get('/cliqforum/ajax/ang_thread').success(function(data){

            $scope.users = data;
        });   
  });
}
```

This is the part I can't figure out.  My logo is supposed to clear whatever filter is on the current 'user' data.  However, it sits outside the scope (and I imagine I shouldn't expand the scope to be the entire page?)

I have read something about `scope.$spply` but can't quite figure out what I'm supposed to do:

```
 $('.logo').on('click', 'a', function() {
         scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.users = data;
        });
    });
```

It's not quite necessary that I do it THIS way...I would just like to do what is correct!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I imagine I shouldn't expand the scope to be the entire page?

Why not? That's definitely the way to do it. Just include the logo into the scope and you can then access it from your application, and use `ng-click` to add a click handler.

In fact, you should avoid using jQuery click handlers within your application. You could transform your JavaScript like so:

```
$scope.tableHeaderClick = function() {
    $http.get('/cliqforum/ajax/ang_thread').success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data;
    });   
});
```

Then update the HTML like so:

```
<tr class='table_header' ng-click="tableHeaderClick()">
```

Comment: Thanks! About 'why not': I suppose I had the idea of .on() from jquery in my head.

Answer (score 1):

it is an angular anti-pattern to include DOM elements in controller.  you want to use the ng-click directive to respond to click events

see this plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/KRyvifRYm5SMpbVvWNfc?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, appreciate all the info I can get.